# How to populate a UIImageView with a property list string

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, plist

I'm trying to load image from a plist to a custom cell.
It all works fine with the label, but when I run the app with the imageview, it crashes.

Cell.h:

```
@interface WineCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *bottleImageView;

@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
cell.nameLabel.text = [[wine libraryItemAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Name"];
cell.bottleImageView.image = [[wine libraryItemAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Image"];
```

Crash report:

2012-06-20 01:41:08.975 Appen[3862:f803] Could not load the "bottle" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "NOVAFORLAG.R-dvinsguiden"
2012-06-20 01:41:08.978 Rødvinsguiden[3862:f803] -[__NSCFString _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d7b800

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
cell.bottleImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[wine libraryItemAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Image"]];
```

as the plist file can only store the name of images.

Comment: Or you could encode the images and put them in there as NSData (but certainly no the best approach).